# Properties not being assigned, unable to return values from Private as they are all zero (0)

Tags: vb.net, class, properties

Not all properties are being assigned correctly. Yet two properties are working. Now, I am aware of the Public ReadOnly auto correction, but I prefer the old get/set method because it helps me to understand more thoroughly. I have in a separate file, another class BusinessLogic:

```
Public Class BusinessLogic
    Private _totalPiecesOfAllUsers As Integer
    Private _totalCountOfUsers As Integer
    Private _totalEarningsOfAllUsers As Decimal
    Private _totalAverageOfAllUsers As Decimal
    Private _name As String
    Private _pieces As String
    Private _individualEarning As Decimal

    Public Property TotalPiecesOfAllUsers() As Integer
        Get
            Return _totalPiecesOfAllUsers
        End Get
        Set
            _totalPiecesOfAllUsers += _pieces
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TotalCountOfUsers() As Integer
        Get
            Return _totalCountOfUsers
        End Get
        Set
            _totalCountOfUsers = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TotalEarningsOfAllUsers() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _totalEarningsOfAllUsers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _totalEarningsOfAllUsers = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property TotalAverageOfAllUsers() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _totalAverageOfAllUsers
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _totalAverageOfAllUsers = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Pieces() As Integer
        Get
            Return _pieces
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _pieces = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property IndividualEarning() As Decimal
        Get
            Return _individualEarning
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Decimal)
            _individualEarning = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

And then my Form1

```
  Private Sub CalcPayToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalcPayToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Try
        ' Create Object
        Dim blog As New BusinessLogic
        If tbName.Text <> String.Empty And tbPieces.Text <> String.Empty Then

            ' Get Transactions Per User
            blog.Name = tbName.Text
            blog.Pieces = Integer.Parse(tbPieces.Text)
            blog.IndividualEarning = CalculatePieces(blog.Pieces)

            ' Counter Per User
            blog.TotalCountOfUsers += 1

            ' Get Total of all users
            blog.TotalPiecesOfAllUsers += blog.Pieces
            blog.TotalEarningsOfAllUsers += blog.IndividualEarning
            blog.TotalAverageOfAllUsers += (blog.TotalEarningsOfAllUsers / blog.TotalCountOfUsers)
        Else
            ' SHow error if field is empty
            MsgBox("Name and/or Piece count required")
        End If

        ' Assign asmount earned txtbox the calculated value
        lblAmountEarned.Text = FormatCurrency(blog.IndividualEarning)

    Catch exc As Exception
        ' Show error if triggered
        MsgBox("Error processing data, values may be empty or incorrect.")
    End Try
End Sub

Public Function CalculatePieces(ByVal p As Decimal) As Decimal
    ' For piece claculation 
    Dim earningsByPiece As Decimal = 0D

    ' If pieces fall within range 1-199 
    If p >= 1 And p <= 199 Then
        earningsByPiece = p * 0.5
        ' If pieces fall within range 200-399
    ElseIf p >= 200 And p <= 399 Then
        earningsByPiece = p * 0.55
        ' If pieces fall within range 100-599
    ElseIf p >= 400 And p <= 599 Then
        earningsByPiece = p * 0.6
        ' If pieces fall out of 600 range
    ElseIf p >= 600 Then
        earningsByPiece = p * 0.65
    End If
    Return earningsByPiece
End Function
```

Somehow it returns the IndividualEarning, but when I set a break in the BusinessLogic, none of the vraiables are holding anything.

Comment: The setter for `BusinessLogic.TotalPiecesOfAllUsers` doesn't actually use the passed in `value` - was that intentional?  It probably should look like the other property setters (or better yet move to inline properties).  It's not obvious to user of this class what would happen.  Not sure it's related to your problem or not, but it could be a problem later.

Comment: ...and `Pieces` is declared as integer but its backing field is of type string and it's also summed (as mentioned, in the setter[?]) to `_totalPiecesOfAllUsers`, also of type integer  (I'm not sure how all this lets you understand better what is going on). What is the *Public ReadOnly auto correction*?

Comment: Its the Get/Set that helps me understand it, rather than seeing the One line of Public ReadOnly

Comment: I was instructed to user ReadOnly properties or Private properties with public accessors. But I am unable to assign the private fields  with any of the public accessors.

Comment: @herboren Can you describe in more detail where exactly your breakpoint is set, and what variables you are inspecting?  If you set a breakpoint on the one line between Set/End Set of your Properties in BusinessLogic, the debugger will break before the value is set into the private field.  You have to execute (step over) that line before the private field will get updated.  If this isn’t your problem, please try describing it even more.

Comment: I made a quick desk recording, not sure what the rules are, but I compiled an ran w/ breakpoints and what I am trying to obtain. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4FyNjruSao

Comment: The `CalcPayToolStripMenuItem.Click` event creates an instance of your class. You set several properties of your instance object and display one of them in a label. Then your object falls out of scope. No other procedures can use this object and the properties are lost.

Comment: Im a little confused, where exactly does it fall out of scope?

Comment: At the `End Sub` .  You used a `Dim blog As New BusinessLogic` inside the Sub so, as soon as the code reaches `End Sub` it is gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have started on the wrong foot. Reworking this code, I would start with a class called `User`. I added a custom constructor so you can add a new user in a single line of code. Then I added back the default constructor.

```
Public Class User
    Public Property Name() As String
    Public Property Pieces() As Integer
    Public Property IndividualEarning() As Decimal

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Public Sub New(nme As String, pcs As Integer, earnings As Decimal)
        Name = nme
        Pieces = pcs
        IndividualEarning = earnings
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then I created a business logic class to hold the rest of the information. The properties are `Shared` so they are the same whenever the class is referenced. There is no need to create an instance when you are accessing shared members. Just refer to them with the class name.

```
Public Class BL
    Public Shared Property TotalPiecesOfAllUsers() As Integer
    Public Shared Property TotalCountOfUsers() As Integer
    Public Shared Property TotalEarningsOfAllUsers() As Decimal
    Public Shared Property TotalAverageOfAllUsers() As Decimal
End Class
```

Then in the `Form` I created a `List(Of User)` to hold your User objects.
Now, when you create a User, even though the `u` will fall out of scope, the user is safely tucked away in the list with the `.Add` method.

Every time you adjust the contents of the list you call `CalculateTotalsAndAverage` to keep your `BL` class up to date.

```
Dim lst As New List(Of User)

Private Sub CalcPayToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalcPayToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Validate input
    If tbName.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a name")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim pcs As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(tbPieces.Text, pcs) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number of pieces")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim u As New User
    u.Name = tbName.Text
    u.Pieces = pcs
    u.IndividualEarning = CalculatePieces(pcs)
    lst.Add(u)
    CalculateTotalsAndAverage()
    lblAmountEarned.Text = FormatCurrency(u.IndividualEarning)
End Sub

Public Function CalculatePieces(ByVal p As Integer) As Decimal
    Dim earnings As Decimal = 0D
    Select Case p
        Case 1 To 199
            earnings = p * 0.5D
        Case 200 To 399
            earnings = p * 0.55D
        Case 400 To 599
            earnings = p * 0.6D
        Case Else
            earnings = p * 0.65D
    End Select
    Return earnings
End Function

Private Sub CalculateTotalsAndAverage()
    BL.TotalAverageOfAllUsers = lst.Average(Function(u) u.IndividualEarning)
    BL.TotalPiecesOfAllUsers = lst.Sum(Function(u) u.Pieces)
    BL.TotalCountOfUsers = lst.Count
    BL.TotalEarningsOfAllUsers = lst.Sum(Function(u) u.IndividualEarning)
    Debug.Print($"Average {BL.TotalAverageOfAllUsers} Total Pieces {BL.TotalPiecesOfAllUsers} Total Earnings {BL.TotalEarningsOfAllUsers}")
End Sub
```

Comment: I did mark your rework as the solution and I used bits and pieces, but I did not use all of your code. The idea of using List(Of Object) was genius and that nailed it, as well as changing the properties to Public Shared Property. Everything came out in the Summary correctly, Ty.